# cascade realisation from direct realisation

Tags: discrete-signals, filter-design, digital-filters

I am trying to convert filter realisation from Direct form 1 to cascade using function provided from Digital signal processing by Proakis. I designed lowpass IIR filter and extracted numerator and denominator coefficients. I used fvtool to plot pole zero as well as magnitude response. But when I use dir2cas function provided in textbook, matlab shows an error while plotting using fvtool. Can someone help?

The filter function:

```
filte = designfilt('lowpassiir','PassbandRipple',1,'StopbandAttenuation',30, ...
'PassbandFrequency', 3.4e3, 'StopbandFrequency', 4e3, ...
'SampleRate', 16e3);
sos = filte.Coefficients;
[b,a] = sos2tf(filte.Coefficients);
%fvtool(sos);

[b0, B0, A0] = dir2cas(b,a);
fvtool(B0,A0);
```

The direct to cascade function:

```
function [b0, B, A] = dir2cas(b,a);
b0 = b(1);
b = b/b0;
a0 = a(1);
a = a/a0;

b0 = b0/a0;
M = length(b);
N = length(a);

if N >M
    b = [b zeros(1, N-M)];
elseif M > N
    a = [a zeros(1, N-M)];
    N = M;
else
    NM = 0;
end

k = floor(N/2);
B = zeros(k,3);
A = zeros(k,3);

if k*2 == N;
    b = [b 0];
    a = [a 0];
end

broots = cplxpair(roots(b));
aroots = cplxpair(roots(a));
for i = 1:2:2*k
    Brow = broots(i:1:i+1,:);
    Brow = real(poly(Brow));
    B(fix((i +1)/2),:) = Brow;
    Arow = aroots(i:1:i+1,:);
    Arow = real(poly(Arow));
    A(fix((i+1)/2),:) = Arow;
end
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because reading the documentation of `fvtool` should solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Matt, I went through fvtool documentation, however it still says error. Moreover after converting to cascade, I have 3 outputs numerator, denominator and bo constant, which connects 2 cascade functions.